# Mongoid has_and_belongs_to_many associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I trying to get mongoid to save associations, but I can only get one side to work. If I have the following test.

```
  test "should add a user as a follower when a user follows the group" do                                                                                                                                        
    @cali_group.followers = []                                                                                                                                                
    @user1.followed_groups << @cali_group                                                                                                                                                  
    assert_equal 1, @user1.followed_groups.count
    assert_equal 1, @cali_group.followers.count
  end
```

Which is failing, because @cali_group.followers is []. I've been working with this for awhile, tried `@cali_group.reload`. But it looks like the only way to do this in my code is to work both ends of the join, i.e. `@cali_group.followers << @user1`. I can do that in my code if I have to.

The models for polco_group and user are here: https://gist.github.com/1195048

Full test code is here: https://gist.github.com/1195052

Comment: You do not have the :inverse_of set on user side, may be thats causing you the problems.

Comment: good point, i'll look into that

Comment: hmm. . .still not working -- but a needed improvement in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be that:
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1204

Comment: yep, it is -- tested and it is a caching issue

Comment: The link by @sandrew is no longer valid.
A similar issue was reported here:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/pull/3604

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the show. Using Mongoid 4.0.2 here. The issue is troubling me as well.

The link by @sandrew is no longer valid. A similar issue was reported here: http://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/pull/3604

The workaround that I found was:

```
@cali_group.followers = []
@cali_group.follower_ids # Adding this line somehow does something to the cache
@user1.followed_groups << @cali_group
```

Found this workaround by adding a before_save in the Group class and observing `self.changes`. Without this line, the `follower_ids` member changes from `nil` to `[]`. However after adding the line, the correct ID of the user is received and set. Hope that helps any future reader.