# how to make has_and_belongs_to_many relationship work in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

i have the following code in the rails company model:

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name,      type: String
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

User model:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  field :email,           type: String
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

There is a company record in the database, and a user record and they are associated. For some reason, the following code does NOT work:

```
c = Company.first
c.users # returns empty array
```

similarly, the followign code does not work:

```
u = User.first
u.companies
```

But the following code DOES work:

```
c = Company.first
user = User.find c.user_ids.first
```

and the following code also works:

```
u = User.first
company = Company.find u.company_ids.first
```

so if i try to access users from the company.users, it does not work, but the user_ids array does have a list of user ids, and when i try to access the users from this list, it works. How can i fix this issue?

i am using rails 3.2.5 and mongoid 3.0.0.rc

Comment: I noticed that when creating the association by `user.companies << company`, I got `user.companies` as expected but `company.users` worked differently, returning a query. I could see that array by calling `company.users.all.to_a`. Following that I called `company.users << user2` this really seemed to mess with the associations.

Comment: Very late to the show. This workaround did it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308539/mongoid-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations/36282420#36282420

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue ;)
Make sure you're using mongodb version > 2.0.0, for more details see: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#installation

Comment: Yes, i simply did a sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen to reinstall mongodb, (i think i had earlier isntalled it from source about 6 months ago) and it started working after that.