# Rails Mongoid HABTM association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, mongoid

I'm new with Mongoid/MongoDB with Rails. I want to create has_and_belongs_to_many asscoiation between User and Project.

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String

  validates_presence_of :title, :description

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ## Database authenticatable
  field :email,              type: String, default: ""
  field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: ""

  ## Recoverable
  field :reset_password_token,   type: String
  field :reset_password_sent_at, type: Time

  ## Rememberable
  field :remember_created_at, type: Time

  ## Trackable
  field :sign_in_count,      type: Integer, default: 0
  field :current_sign_in_at, type: Time
  field :last_sign_in_at,    type: Time
  field :current_sign_in_ip, type: String
  field :last_sign_in_ip,    type: String

  ## Confirmable
  # field :confirmation_token,   type: String
  # field :confirmed_at,         type: Time
  # field :confirmation_sent_at, type: Time
  # field :unconfirmed_email,    type: String # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # field :failed_attempts, type: Integer, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # field :unlock_token,    type: String # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # field :locked_at,       type: Time


  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

But when I go to the console, it looks like they are not connected.

> { "_id" : ObjectId("564ddf63c705146553000001"), "title" : "Project 1
>   ", "description" : "....." }
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("564dddc6c70514618c00000b"), "email" :
>   "user1@mail.com", "encrypted_password" :
>   "$2a$10$xUAdz9V64IEH9oufE3kYauzZ/.xa5GBr/0lapZDnSkwca40jH8/i6",
>   "sign_in_count" : 1, "reset_password_token" : null,
>   "reset_password_sent_at" : null, "last_sign_in_at" :
>   ISODate("2015-11-19T14:33:43.293Z"), "current_sign_in_at" :
>   ISODate("2015-11-19T14:33:43.293Z"), "last_sign_in_ip" : "::1",
>   "current_sign_in_ip" : "::1" }

I expected to have project_ids for User and user_ids for Project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you set-up another table?

Comment: Hello, Nithin! No, I haven't. On mongodb.org Mongoid 5 Tutorial it is written, that no join collection is needed. How should I create a common table? I'm a complete newbie with it.

Comment: oh yes that's right, not much hands with mongoid, may be you have seen this by now http://stackoverflow.com/q/11096691/2231236.

Comment: My mongodb is 3.0.7. This is so strange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I simply should have watched in rails console, not a mongodb console. I still don't understand, why these consoles show different results. But in rails console there were my project_ids for User and user_ids for Project. So HABTM works!